# Read in a JSON Array and convert to a IEnumerable

Tags: c#, json

[image]

I've never worked with JSON files but I have the task to implement the JSON file and I need to convert it to a IEnumerable. When I try to deserzialize the JSON object I get an exception which says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Price_Algorithm.AuctionInfo'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

My code:

```
var data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\benatia.json");
var terry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AuctionInfo>>(data);

public class AuctionInfo : IEnumerable
{
    public string BidState { get; set; }
    public uint BuyNowPrice { get; set; }
    public uint CurrentBid { get; set; }
    public int Expires { get; set; }
    public ItemData ItemData { get; set; }
    public uint StartingBid { get; set; }
    public string TradeState { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I've uploaded the JSON object so everyone knows the content of the whole JSON file: http://puu.sh/fancH/9a495ecbe9.json (new JSON)

Comment: Show your code for `AuctionInfo` and any other custom types it references.

Comment: Added the auctionInfo code and a visualized json screenshot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com) the classes you should be deserializing into should look like this:

```
public class AttributeList
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class LifeTimeStat
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class StatsList
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class ItemData
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    public List<AttributeList> AttributeList { get; set; }
    public int CardSubTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Contract { get; set; }
    public int DiscardValue { get; set; }
    public int Fitness { get; set; }
    public string Formation { get; set; }
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public int InjuryGames { get; set; }
    public string InjuryType { get; set; }
    public string ItemState { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public int LastSalePrice { get; set; }
    public int LeagueId { get; set; }
    public int LifeTimeAssists { get; set; }
    public List<LifeTimeStat> LifeTimeStats { get; set; }
    public int LoyaltyBonus { get; set; }
    public int Morale { get; set; }
    public int Owners { get; set; }
    public int PlayStyle { get; set; }
    public string PreferredPosition { get; set; }
    public int RareFlag { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public List<StatsList> StatsList { get; set; }
    public int Suspension { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int Training { get; set; }
    public bool Untradeable { get; set; }
    public int Pile { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string BidState { get; set; }
    public int BuyNowPrice { get; set; }
    public int CurrentBid { get; set; }
    public int Expires { get; set; }
    public ItemData ItemData { get; set; }
    public int Offers { get; set; }
    public string SellerEstablished { get; set; }
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public string SellerName { get; set; }
    public int StartingBid { get; set; }
    public object TradeId { get; set; }
    public string TradeState { get; set; }
    public object Watched { get; set; }
}
```

I took the JSON from the link you posted, threw it into a file, and put together a little console application that does the following:

```
var data = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var auctions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RootObject>>(data);
```

Here's a link to the solution I built http://1drv.ms/1ChmYYx but it's really no more than what I already posted.

Worked perfectly, I got 26 instances of `RootObject`.

If you want you can rename `RootObject` to something else. I just cut-and-pasted directly from what json2charp generated.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it but its still throwing the same exception :/.

Comment: Maybe you have another idea? I could also upload the Visual Studio project which only tries to import this JSon Array ?

Comment: Interesting, because I downloaded your JSON file using the link you provided and wrote the code and it worked perfectly. If it's still throwing an exception then the JSON isn't what you posted or you're not using the classes or deserialization code I posted, because there should be no reference to AuctionInfo anymore. I have updated the body to include a little more information.

Comment: This works for me as well, and the classes are indeed the same, the only difference is that I read in the json file directly from my disc instead of importing it into the project. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead:

```
var data = "[" + File.ReadAllText(@"C:\benatia.json") + "]";
var terry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AuctionInfo>>(data);
```

Your JSON file is slightly malformed, since it contains multiple JSON objects separated by commas, but no surrounding square brackets `[` ... `]`, which would define a JSON array.

I have added the square brackets to your `data` string.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, this was me who deleted thois '[' and ']'. It doesn't work with those signs as well, thats why I tried that. I will upload the original JSon file and edit it.

Comment: Do you have another idea maybe ?